# "a newcomers" singular or plural

Tags: phrase-usage, singular-vs-plural

According to google search, "a **newcomers**" is used in many websites.

is it singular or plural?

And if it's plural, why do we add **a** in front of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I searched "a newcomers" (no apostrophe) newcomers was always being used as part of compound noun, eg. "a newcomers guide" = "a guide for newcomers".

Therefore the "a" is appropriate because it can refer to a singular noun, that is being described as for newcomers.